# UserErrorException: UserErrorException:

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Currently I am using azure ml when I run below code :

```
file_dataset =  Dataset.get_by_name(workspace=ws, name='voice_recognition_expreimnt')
mounted_dataset = file_dataset.mount()
```

I got this error:

```
UserErrorException: UserErrorException:
    Message: Mount is only supported on Unix or Unix-like operating systems and the FUSE library must be present. For more information, please refer to the remarks section of FileDataset.mount's documentation. Execution failedunexpectedly due to OSError
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Mount is only supported on Unix or Unix-like operating systems and the FUSE library must be present. For more information, please refer to the remarks section of FileDataset.mount's documentation. Execution failedunexpectedly due to OSError"
    }
}
```

I am using Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I also install blobfuse by run these commands:

```
1 wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
2 sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
3 sudo apt-get update
4 sudo apt-get install blobfuse
```

can somebody tell what is the problem here?.

Comment: Well, you wrote code that tries to mount a drive, and the error message tells you, in as many words: "Message: Mount is only supported on Unix or Unix-like operating systems and the FUSE library must be present." What part of that is unclear, exactly? For example, do we need to explain what a "Unix-like operating system" is? It also says "For more information, please refer to the remarks section of FileDataset.mount's documentation." Did you try doing that? If you are not willing to read what the program tells you, why should we expect you will read anything we tell you?

Answer (score 0):

We do not officially support Ubuntu 20. As a workaround, you can follow the .NET Core official guide to install .NET Core 2.1. let us know whether it resolve your problem. Thanks!

```
apt install curl wget
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
apt update
apt install -y dotnet-runtime-2.1
```